# pentaho 6 requiere-cfg-js not found in plugin

Tags: pentaho

I have a situation, I'm developing a plugin with version 6 of pentaho, some me things work and others do not and this is because not myplugin-require-js-cfg.js file is, I was researching in case I made a plugin configuration in the xml:
[plugin.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fwqm8.png)

and in the myplugin-require-js-cfg.js file:

`(function() {
 requireCfg['paths']['search'] = CONTEXT_PATH + 'content/idplugin/folderresource/js';
})();`

but still gives me the same error:

**ERROR [GenericServlet] GenericServlet.ERROR_0004 - Resource /idplugin/folderresource/myplugin-require-js-cfg.js not found in plugin myplugin**

I have tried several things but still gives the same problem,
someone can give me an idea ?, would greatly appreciate it, thanks in advance

Comment: Couple of questions: (1) Do you have the file myplugin-require-js-cfg.js at system/idplugin/folderresource ? (2) are you using require.js in the client-side and is that why you're introducing the require-js-cfg file ? Because if you aren't using require.js, you do not need that file.

Comment: yes, I have the file required on this route, and what I'm trying to do with that is to use a plug-in autocomplete jquery, I'm doing a sparkl plugin, and use the plugin jquery to make a list of possible outcomes, but this me gives the following error Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define () module: function, I thought it is because not find the file myplugin-require-js-cfg.js, any help will be apretiated

Comment: Can't you just add the jquery plugin as a resource to the dashboard ? That's probably easier.

Comment: thanks Pedro, I find the file-cfg-js required, but now I get the following error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in -require-js-cfg.js context=mantle&cssOnly=true: 1, i import the webcontext like this <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"   src="webcontext.js?context=requirejs&requireJsOnly=true"></script> .    is the context wrong??

Comment: when i tried get acces to my -require-js-cfg.js file get this error pt.webdetails.cpk.CpkContentGenerator cannot be cast to org.pentaho.platform.api.engine.IContentGenerator